# how to create a trigger event whenever the my models are populated in admin?

Tags: django, model, triggers

I want to create a trigger that will send the model's data to my script whenever they are populated via admin. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check out the [signal system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/). You can use `post_save` to access the data of the object and use external functions on them. You may need celery if the external script is task-heavy.

Comment: I just want to import the model data into csv whenever its updated.

Comment: Yes you can do that. The signal I mentioned will yield the instance which then you can access all of its fields.